# Rademacher random variables limit

Tags: probability, probability-theory, characteristic-functions, rademacher-distribution

> Let $X_1, X_2,\dots$ be an i.i.d sequence of random variables on a probability space $(\Omega,$ *F*$, \mathbb{P})$ with $\mathbb{P}(X_1 = 1) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 = −1) = \frac12$.
>
> 1. Show that $\phi_{X_i} (t) = \cos(t)$. ($\phi$ denotes the characteristic function)
> 2. Use 1 to prove that for every $t\in \mathbb{R}$ $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos^n(\frac{t}n)=1$.
> 3. Use 2 to show that the weak law of large numbers holds for $X_i$’s, i.e., that $\frac{X_1+\dots+X_n}n\to0$ in prob.

My attempt:

1. We have $\phi_{X_i}(t)=\mathbb{E}[e^{iX_it}]=\frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}2=\cos(t)$
2. Here I already get stuck: how should I use my prevoius result? Do I have to consider maybe $(\cos(\frac {t}n))^n=(\frac{e^{i\frac{t}n}+e^{-i\frac{t}n}}2)^n$??

3. From a Corollary I know that for $S:=X_1+\dots+X_n$ we have $\phi_S(t)=\phi_{X_1}(t)\cdots\phi_{X_n}(t)=\cos^n(t)\not=\cos^n(\frac{t}n)$, so how do I employ part (2)?
   Then maybe we should get that $\frac{X_1+\dots+X_n}n\to\frac1n\to0$ pointwise (so why ask for convergence in probability?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: In your approach for point 2 you forgot the $t/n$. For point 3 you can't converge to $1/n$ as $n$ tends to infinity. If your issue is that $cos^n(t)\neq cos^n(\frac{t}{n})$, maybe you should simply use a different value of $t$.

Answer (score 1):

For (2) write $\cos^n(t/n)=\exp(n\ln(\cos(t/n)))$. Then
\begin{align}
n\ln(\cos(t/n))&=\frac{\ln(\cos(t/n))}{1-\cos(t/n)}\times \frac{1-\cos(t/n)}{1/n} \\
&\to -1\times 0
\end{align}
as $n\to\infty$. (Note that $\lim_{x\to 0}\ln(1-x)/x=-1$.)

As for $(3)$, write
$$
\varphi_{S_n/n}(t)=\left(\varphi_{X_1}(t/n)\right)^n=\cos^n(t/n).
$$
Since the RHS converges to $1$ (the ch.f of $\delta_0$), $S_n/n\xrightarrow{d}0$, implying that $S_n/n\xrightarrow{p}0$.

Comment: the assignment asks to use 1. to prove 2. though..

Comment: @Exodd The only way that I see here (1 implies 2) is to use the WLLN, which is proved in (3) using (2) :)